# Splitting one csv to multiple using rows unique value in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, pandas-groupby

What is below is what I have currently with the question and file I have.

Here is what I have so far:

```
filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,0,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,1,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":214,""cy"":76,""r"":96}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,2,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":400,""cy"":48,""r"":86}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,3,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":593,""cy"":58,""r"":99}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,4,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":777,""cy"":-15,""r"":93}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,0,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,1,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":214,""cy"":76,""r"":96}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,2,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":400,""cy"":48,""r"":86}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,3,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":593,""cy"":58,""r"":99}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,4,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":777,""cy"":-15,""r"":93}",{}
```

I want to split data into multiple CSV like below:
It should be like this:

```
filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,0,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,1,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":214,""cy"":76,""r"":96}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,2,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":400,""cy"":48,""r"":86}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,3,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":593,""cy"":58,""r"":99}",{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,4,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":777,""cy"":-15,""r"":93}",{}


filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,0,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,1,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":214,""cy"":76,""r"":96}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,2,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":400,""cy"":48,""r"":86}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,3,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":593,""cy"":58,""r"":99}",{}
AN7_2Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,4,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":777,""cy"":-15,""r"":93}",{}
```

```
filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
AN7_3Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,0,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}",{}
AN7_3Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,1,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":214,""cy"":76,""r"":96}",{}
AN7_3Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,2,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":400,""cy"":48,""r"":86}",{}
AN7_3Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,3,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":593,""cy"":58,""r"":99}",{}
AN7_3Cropped.jpg,2544654,{},215,4,"{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":777,""cy"":-15,""r"":93}",{}
```

```
class SeprateCsvFiles:
      def separateCSV(self,iPath,oPath):

        for key, rows in groupby(csv.reader(open(iPath, 'r')),
                                 lambda row: row[0]):
            with open(oPath+"%s.csv" % key, "w") as output:
                for row in rows:
                    output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

What I'm getting as output is below:

```
filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,0,{"name":"circle","cx":1001,"cy":258,"r":96},{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,1,{"name":"circle","cx":804,"cy":331,"r":90},{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,2,{"name":"circle","cx":955,"cy":448,"r":100},{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,3,{"name":"circle","cx":620,"cy":400,"r":103},{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,4,{"name":"circle","cx":451,"cy":509,"r":99},{}
AN7_1Cropped.jpg,2321174,{},196,5,{"name":"circle","cx":649,"cy":584,"r":84},{}
```

> "{""name"":""circle"",""cx"":17,""cy"":69,""r"":102}"

above format got changed in below. " are missing

> {"name":"circle","cx":1001,"cy":258,"r":96}

Answer (score 0):

Read the header before doing group by and then prepend the header to each of your resulting csv objects.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. It worked. got a new problem.